# Issue with Alphabetical Selection Sort program

Tags: c++, selection-sort, alphabetical-sort

I'm having an issue with a homework problem involving the Selection Sort concept. We were given a skeleton code within which we need to complete the `bool compare(...)` and `void selectionsort(...)` functions, which I have done. Then, running the program should sort the strings given in `main()` alphabetically, and prints them in alphabetical order after printing the initial strings. However, mine doesn't sort it alphabetically and after trying to change multiple things I am stuck on figuring out why.

Please note the only things I am allowed to edit are the `compare` and `selectionsort` methods, nothing else. We are required to use the `compare` method (which returns true if the first string comes sooner in the alphabet than the other string, did that) within the `selectionsort` method in order to compare them, rather than a simple comparison `< > =` statement.

I believe my problem has something to do with that `if` statement within the `for` loop but I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out the correct way to do it. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

bool compare(char *str1, char *str2, int strLen1, int strLen2) { // complete this method
    int small;
    if(strLen1 > strLen2)
        small = strLen2;
    else
        small = strLen1;

    //compare lexicographic values
    for(int i=0; i<small;i++){
        if(str1[i] < str2[i])
            return true;
        else if (str2[i] < str1[i])
            return false;
    }

    if (strLen1 < strLen2)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

void selectionsort(char **strings, int numStrings, int *eachStringLen) { // complete this method
    /* strings = jagged array
    numStrings = numRows
    eachStringLen = numColumnsInEachRow*/

    for(int i=0; i<numStrings-1;i++){
        int minIndex = i;
        if(compare(strings[i], strings[i+1], eachStringLen[i], eachStringLen[i+1]) == false){
        for(int j=i+1;j<numStrings;j++){
            if(strings[j]<strings[minIndex])
                minIndex = j;
        }
    }

        //swap strings[minIndex] and strings[i]
        char *tempA = strings[i];
        strings[i] = strings[minIndex];
        strings[minIndex] = tempA;

        int tempB = eachStringLen[i];
        eachStringLen[i] = eachStringLen[minIndex];
        eachStringLen[minIndex] = tempB;

    }//end for i
}//end selectionsort

int main() {
    char str0[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c' };
    char str1[] = { 'x', 'y', 'z', 'w' };
    char str2[] = { 'x', 'y', 'z', 'a', 'b' };
    char str3[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'x' };
    char str4[] = { 'w', 'x', 'c', 'd', 'x' };
    char str5[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'x', 'y' };
    char str6[] = { 'a', 'a', 'c' };
    char str7[] = { 'w', 'x', 'c', 'd', 'x' };
    char str8[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'x'};
    char *strings[] = { str0, str1, str2, str3, str4, str5, str6, str7, str8 };
    int eachStringLength[] = { sizeof(str0) / sizeof(char), sizeof(str1)
            / sizeof(char), sizeof(str2) / sizeof(char), sizeof(str3)
            / sizeof(char), sizeof(str4) / sizeof(char), sizeof(str5)
            / sizeof(char), sizeof(str6) / sizeof(char), sizeof(str7)
            / sizeof(char), sizeof(str8)
            / sizeof(char) };
    int numStrings = 9;
    cout << "*** Original Strings ***" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < numStrings; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < eachStringLength[i]; j++) {
            cout << strings[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    selectionsort(strings, numStrings, eachStringLength);
    cout << endl << "*** Sorted Strings ***" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < numStrings; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < eachStringLength[i]; j++) {
            cout << strings[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yep, that's part of the code we were given and cannot edit. I think that's just used to calculate each value in the array `eachStringLength[]`

Comment: IMO, whoever gave you this assignment needs to take their own C++ programming course.

Comment: You need to find the minimum index of *all* the strings starting at `i` and then swap.  You are missing an inner loop.  Note that if your method would work, then you would have implemented an order N comparison sort.  ;)

Comment: also, you could just use `std::swap` instead of a temp variable and three lines.

Comment: @MFisherKDX After going over it I added an inner loop below the `int minIndex = i` declaration (see code above), which is somewhat closer but still doesn't quite come out correct. And what do you mean by order N comparison sort?

Comment: For all the C++ness of the code you could replace `iostream` with `stdio.h` and `cout` with `printf` and it would be C. Also note `*strings[]` is not any array of pointers to strings, it is an array of pointers to character arrays. There is no *nul-termination*. `eachStringLength[]` elements are the number of elements in each array for the same reason. All of which is fine, but for the very confusing misnomers used throughout your code naming things as "string...".

Comment: @BoolBordan07 All of this `char *` and char array stuff in your code could have all been replaced by `std::string` **and** at the same time, have an assignment with the same requirements (you having to write a selection sort).  All of the `C`-code "obfuscation" need not be necessary at all if your course is actually a C++ course.  This code seems to be ripped-off from a `C` language example with no changes except for the output being `cout` instead of `printf`.

Answer (score 1):

Your sorting logic is slightly off.  You need two loops as [selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) is O(N^2), and [no comparison sort can be faster than O(NlogN)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort#Number_of_comparisons_required_to_sort_a_list).

The outer loop should iterate over each index i.  The inner loop should find the smallest element in the range i to N and swap it with the element at i.

I would also suggest you use `std::swap` to make your code more readable.

Thus the meat of your code should look like:

```
for(int i=0; i<numStrings;++i){
    int minIndex = i;
    for(int j=i+1;j<numStrings;++j){
        if(compare(strings[j], strings[minIndex], eachStringLen[j], eachStringLen[minIndex])){
            minIndex = j;
        }
    }

    std::swap(strings[i], strings[minIndex]);
    std::swap(eachStringLen[i], eachStringLen[minIndex]);
}//end for i
```

Note you can write your outer loop to continue on `i<numStrings` instead of `i<numStrings-1` because the last element will necessarily swap with itself.  But both exit conditions are ok.

The output is:

```
*** Original Strings ***
abc
xyzw
xyzab
abcdx
wxcdx
abcxy
aac
wxcdx
abcx

*** Sorted Strings ***
aac
abc
abcdx
abcx
abcxy
wxcdx
wxcdx
xyzab
xyzw
```

Comment: Oh I see, I was looking in all the wrong places, whereas my input for the `compare` function was the problem. Thanks! However, the output is still slightly incorrect and not completely alphabetical; i.e. the string "abc" prints before "aac" when looking at the second letter, "a" obviously comes before "b". Would I then have to add a third nested loop within `for(int j` that would check the second letter of each string?

Comment: No. Two loops is sufficient.  Check your code, you should be getting the output I posted.

Comment: Ah, yep, my mistake. I had messed around with the `compare(...)` function trying to fix the output, and then totally forgot about my changes when I tried your solution. Works perfectly now, thanks so much!