# sorting array alphabetically c++

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

Write a program to sort and display the names in alphabet order (use selection sort).The program prompts the user to enter the name being search (use binary search).  The program also makes a correction to upper case the first character of the first and last name.

I can only figure out how to do with the algorithm library but im not allowed to use it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    const int SIZE = 20;
char temp;
int i, j;
bool madeAswap;
char arr[SIZE][SIZE] = { "Collins, Bill", "Smith, Bart", "Michalski, Joe",
    "Griffin, Jim","Sanchez, Manny", "Rubin, Sarah", "Taylor, Tyrone",
    "Johnson, Jill","Allison, Jeff", "Moreno, Juan", "Wolfe, Bill",
    "Whitman, Jean","Moretti, Bella", "Wu, Hong", "Patel, Renee",
    "Harrison, Rose","Smith, Cathy", "Conroy, Pat", "Kelly, Sean", "Holland, Beth" };
do {
    madeAswap = false;
    for (i = 1; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        for (j = 1; j < SIZE; j++)
        {
            if (strcmp(arr[j - 1], arr[j]) > 0)
            {
                temp = arr[i][i];
                arr[i][i] = arr[i + 1][i + 1];
                arr[i + 1][i + 1] = temp;
                madeAswap = true;
            }
        }
    }
    }while (madeAswap);
for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
    cout << arr[j][j] << endl;
}
system("pause");
return 0;
```

}

Comment: 1) use std::string. 2) use std::swap. 3) that doesn't look like selection sort. Looks more like bubble sort. 4) array indices start at 0.

Comment: Selection sort is O(N^2) And has two loops. The outer loop iterates over the indices i. The inner loop iterates from i to N and finds the smallest element in the range i to N. You take this element and swap with element i. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56086910/8767209)

Comment: "[I'm] not allowed to use [the standard library]." Then you can't even do what is called I/O.

Comment: BTW, your code attempts to sort twice because of that `do... while(madeAswap)` loop. That logic is wrong. And you aren't swapping strings. You're swapping characters. Why is `temp` declared as `char`? Again, make your life easier. Use std::string and std::swap

Comment: Your question lacks a specific question. How is your current code malfunctioning? What specifically are you asking for help with (assuming you are not asking us to do your homework for you)?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly this is not any sorting algorithm but close to Bubble Sort, a time taking algorithm. Again you are dealing with characters in random manner not with strings.
Have a look on this modification I have done, it will sort only your arrays

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    const int SIZE = 20;
    string temp;
    int i, j;
    string arr[SIZE] = { "Collins, Bill", "Smith, Bart", "Michalski, Joe",
        "Griffin, Jim","Sanchez, Manny", "Rubin, Sarah", "Taylor, Tyrone",
        "Johnson, Jill","Allison, Jeff", "Moreno, Juan", "Wolfe, Bill",
        "Whitman, Jean","Moretti, Bella", "Wu, Hong", "Patel, Renee",
        "Harrison, Rose","Smith, Cathy", "Conroy, Pat", "Kelly, Sean", "Holland, Beth" };
    for (i = 1; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        for (j = 1; j < SIZE; j++)
        {
            if ( arr[j-1] > arr[j])
            {
               temp = arr[j-1];
               arr[j-1] = arr[j];
               arr[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
        cout << arr[j] << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are right, actually I didn't focus on that. Sorry for that.

Comment: Better. I'm holding off on up-voting any answers, though, since I still do not see exactly what the question is supposed to ask (other than "do my homework for me").

Comment: Hey man, I wasn't asking anyone to do my work for me. I was confused about how sorting strings in arrays work. Obviously, I wanted insight on why I couldn't use strcmp(), I made it into a 2D array because I was confused. Maybe you should spend your time explaining things to others to help people learn and progress instead of sharing how you're holding off on an upvote. what's the point in that. If you can't understand the mistakes then move on to a question you can handle. @JaMiT

Comment: This sorting part is only a small portion of my entire program. I've been reading a lot trying to understand the code. I don't need you to discourage me.

Comment: @Brett That's better. Asking about `strcmp()` would have been a good question. Much better than simply presenting your homework assignment and asking for a solution. (Take a look at the question you wrote and try to find some indication of what was confusing you. It's not there.) Since this question has answers, it might be too late to edit this question to make it better, though. A new question is a possibility though.

Comment: @Brett As for the point of mentioning the lack of an up-vote, that was an attempt to not discourage ABHIJIT PRASAD. I had asked for changes. When I got them, my normal response would be to affirm the result with a vote. Rather than leave an impression that nothing is ever good enough, I took the time to explain why I was not voting this time.

Comment: I see, I'm sorry. You're right, I should have been more specific. I was honestly confused on what my question was. Dealing with strings has honestly confused me more than anything else this semester. Right now I'm even confused on why my while loop is skipping my getline() function.

Answer (score 0):

You said that you needed to use "selection sort" but you are using "bubble sort". I modified your program on both loops (for) and also on the string swap (movement).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    const int SIZE = 20;
    string temp;
    int i, j;
    string arr[SIZE] = { "Collins, Bill", "Smith, Bart", "Michalski, Joe",
        "Griffin, Jim","Sanchez, Manny", "Rubin, Sarah", "Taylor, Tyrone",
        "Johnson, Jill","Allison, Jeff", "Moreno, Juan", "Wolfe, Bill",
        "Whitman, Jean","Moretti, Bella", "Wu, Hong", "Patel, Renee",
        "Harrison, Rose","Smith, Cathy", "Conroy, Pat", "Kelly, Sean", "Holland, Beth" };
    for (i = 0; i < (SIZE - 1); i++)
    {
        for (j = (i+1); j < SIZE; j++)
        {
            if ( arr[i] > arr[j])
            {
               temp = arr[i];
               arr[i] = arr[j];
               arr[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
        cout << arr[j] << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

The true "selection sort" has complexity of comparison O (n ^ 2) and complexity of movement O (n). I believe the correct way to implement it should be this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    const int SIZE = 20;
    string temp;
    int i, j;
    string arr[SIZE] = { "Collins, Bill", "Smith, Bart", "Michalski, Joe",
        "Griffin, Jim","Sanchez, Manny", "Rubin, Sarah", "Taylor, Tyrone",
        "Johnson, Jill","Allison, Jeff", "Moreno, Juan", "Wolfe, Bill",
        "Whitman, Jean","Moretti, Bella", "Wu, Hong", "Patel, Renee",
        "Harrison, Rose","Smith, Cathy", "Conroy, Pat", "Kelly, Sean", "Holland, Beth" };
    for (i = 0; i < (SIZE - 1); i++)
    {
        int k = i;
        for (j = (i+1); j < SIZE; j++)
        {
            if ( arr[k] > arr[j])
            {
               k = j;
            }
        }
        if (i != k) {
            temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[k];
            arr[k] = temp;
        }
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
        cout << arr[j] << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Explaining the code: String is a C ++ class that contains an array of characters. The statement 'string arr [SIZE]' is an array of strings of size SIZE. You can refer to the string class at 'http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/'.

Another problem in your code is regarding the ordering. The 'selection sort' sorts a list by comparing an element with the subsequent elements, so your second loop is wrong, it should be: 'for (j = (i + 1); j <SIZE; j ++)'.

Finally, you only need to make the swap (movement) after you've been through the entire j for.

Comment: Thank you so much, so I can just compare string values by writing it as arr[i-1] > arr[i]? i thought I had to use a strcmp(), care to explain how it works?